# Django Admin - 'Cascading' field values based on another field value

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to figure out easiest way to perform the following:

I have a 'Category' Model, a 'Product' Model with a Category ForeignKey, and a 'ProductFeature' EAV-style table referencing a product ForeignKey, a Feature ForeignKey, and a value column. So quick outline of the models/relations involved:

- Category
- Feature.name
- Feature.default_value
- Product.category -> Category
- ProductFeature.product -> Product
- ProductFeature.feature -> Feature
- ProductFeature.value

I would like something like the following experience in Django admin panel:

User creates a new Product via admin app. On the Add new Product page, he can choose a category (already have this with the default Django foreignkey drop down), And then based on the category he chooses, a set of ProductFeature columns should be automatically created and shown, populated with the 'default_value' for those Features. ( I already have a display for all the associated ProductFeature columns on the Product Page using django's TabluarInline widget.)

So what I essentially wanna do is automatically add rows to that display when the category field is changed by the user in admin add page.

What would be the general approach to form something like this? e.g Trigger display of some default rows/values based on the change of value in another form field on the admin page for the model?

Hope I explained myself well, its a bit involved (although I suspect a fairly common requirement for eCommerce-style sites where certain default EAV/ManyToMany type rows should be automatically created based on choosing a type/category for an item/product)

Comment: may be a django-admin skin like `django-grappelli` might have your answer.

Comment: Funny you should mention - was just looking at grappelli earlier today (for whole other reasons) - I don't see immediately how it could help in this case though, can you be more specific perhaps?